# Form Box is not becoming big ...Assist needed

Tags: html, css, forms, contact-form-7

The box is not becoming 100%

```css
input [type="text"],
input [type="e-mail"]{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    
}
```

```html
<p>Full Name &#x2605; <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Jarvis HLD"></p>

            <p>E-Mail &#x2605; <input type="e-mail" name="e-mail" id="e-mail" required placeholder="Jarvis007@outlook.com"></p>
```

I've tried everything
Assist me with it

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's input type="email"  not e-mail.
Second the selector is `input[type="type"]` without space.

```css
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"]{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<p>Full Name &#x2605; <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Jarvis HLD"></p>

            <p>E-Mail &#x2605; <input type="email" name="e-mail" id="e-mail" required placeholder="Jarvis007@outlook.com"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove space after input tag in css.

```css
input[type="text"],
input[type="e-mail"]{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    
}
```

```html
<p>Full Name &#x2605; <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Jarvis HLD"></p>

            <p>E-Mail &#x2605; <input type="e-mail" name="e-mail" id="e-mail" required placeholder="Jarvis007@outlook.com"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Exactly as you wanted. Maybe !?**

```css
.container {
  position relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* background-color: red; */
}

label {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* if you write "something lengthy" it will not get cut" inside label */
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label for=""> Full Name &#x2605; </label>
  <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Jarvis HLD" />
</div>

<br /> <br />

<div class="container">
  <label for=""> E-Mail &#x2605; </label>
  <input type="email" name="e-mail" id="e-mail" required placeholder="Jarvis007@outlook.com" />
</div>
```